# Equivalent resistance in this mosfet circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, digital-logic, cmos

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvIog.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have 3 NMOS are connected as shown above. I need to calculate equivalent resistance as seen by the capacitor so that I am able to calculate time constant for the above two cases.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. What exactly is your question? A well formed question ends with a question mark and can't be answered with yes or no.

Comment: 3/2RonC vs 2RonC for Vc>0

Comment: Hint: this isn't really a pi configuration. Two of your FETs are actually in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Redrawing the ckt like this may ring some bells.

For example the first ckt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmiMNf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- If the mosfet is on, substitute it by its on-resistance \$R_{on}\$
- If the mosfet is off, substitute it by open ckt.
- Find the net resistance that comes across A and B in parallel to capacitor

Comment: The "on resistance" is a strong function of the \$V_{GS}\$ and the transistor characteristics. I fear that assuming that there is a single, fixed value for \$R_{ON}\$ will lead to significant errors. Just the fact that you described the MOSFET states as "on" and "off" suggests a gross oversimplification of reality.

Comment: Yep. But approximations will help on competitive exam questions like this because no information is given on mosfets and how much '1' is.